# DevExpress 15.2 ASP.NET - Server Error in '/' Application (Global.asax)

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, runtime-error, global-asax

I have just installed the **DevExpress 15.2 Demo** and created an ASP.NET Web Application using the default settings and the built-in wizard.

Upon running the web application for the first time I came across an error message:

**Parser Error Message:** Could not load type 'Universal_Web_Reporting.Global_asax'.

```
Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.vb" Inherits="Universal_Web_Reporting.Global_asax" Language="VB" %>
```

I have found other relevant posts associated with the same error message and these point to either an IIS issue or configuration of the build output path \bin\debug as opposed to being just \bin.

Neither of the above solutions rectified my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Having spent over an hour attempting fixes by trial and error I thought I'd share my solution as other **related** posts didn't work for me.

It was quite simple that for some reason the error message was caused by the fact I had included **dots** in my solution name which replaces the 'Inherits' value with underscores **Universal_Web_Reporting.Global_asax** in the page directive.

Changed:

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.vb" Inherits="Universal_Web_Reporting.Global_asax" Language="VB" %>
```

To:

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.vb" Inherits="UniversalWebReporting.Global_asax" Language="VB" %>
```